# Can't run play app on os x lion

Tags: java, playframework

I created an alias like this `alias play=/Users/bobdylan/Documents/play/play`

After creating a new app and trying to run it with `play run` I keep getting this:

```
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >GET / HTTP/1.1< - excepted >JDWP-Handshake<
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >GET / HTTP/1.1< - excepted >JDWP-Handshake<
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That shouldn't prevent your application from starting, only the debugger from being acceessible. It should also show an exception stacktrace which may help us to point the issue (if it's showing in your case please attach it).

To solve the issue, can you check:

1. Ports you are using for Play (maybe you have some other server blocking those ports)
2. The hostname of your computer (you may have localhost pointing somewhere in your host file or some configuration that makes Play fail)

Comment: localhost:8000/ Isn't loading though so I'm not getting a stacktrace. Any idea how I could check for the port? I'm also running Rails, but it's not on the same port (3000)

Comment: default port in Play is 9000, not 8000. The port configuration is at application.conf (conf/ folder)

Comment: The port number seems to have been the problem. Thanks!

Comment: yep. there is a but.. since it says in console "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000" but really uses 9000

Answer (score 0):

JPDA_PORT is set in the play script so you could either edit the play script in the install or you could export it before running play

`export JPDA_PORT=8888`

In the play script change

```
if test "$1" = "debug"; then
  JPDA_PORT="9009"
  shift
fi
```