# Eclipse will not debug play project

Tags: eclipse, playframework, typesafe-activator

I am trying to debug a Play Application in eclipse. When I try to run, eclipse gives an error stating that it timed out at packet 308. Activator constantly outputs:

```
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >GET / HTTP/1.1< - expect
ed >JDWP-Handshake<
```

What is messing up? Eclipse or Activator.

Comment: I'm not specifically sure how to do this myself but i found this thread that you might find your answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791760/cant-run-play-app-on-os-x-lion

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758564/attach-debugger-using-eclipse-to-play-framework-failed) related question? It could be simply a matter of using the correct ports. EDIT:
In case diving into the documentation for Java's debugging infrastructure could be useful, that can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/).